# How can I disable indexing in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, indexing

After researching how to disable indexing, I came across this snippet:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

I have no clue how to implement this. Can someone show a front-end guy how I might go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: open Terminal. paste in the above command. press enter. profit. (probably do this while XCode is not running)

Answer (score 2):

Run Terminal (in Applications/Utilities) and either type that in the command line or copy/paste.